# How to remove const qualifier from a member function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, c++11, function-pointers

I'm using a library which contains the following code:

```
template <typename M>
void _register_member(lua_State *state,
                      const char *member_name,
                      M T::*member) {
    std::function<M(T*)> lambda_get = [member](T *t) {
                //^ error here
        return t->*member;
    };
    //...
```

However this code does not accept `const` member function pointers. Passing those yields the error `Function cannot return function type 'void () const'` or whatever the type of the const member function is.

How do I remove the const qualifier from the passed member function or how do I apply `std::remove_const`?

Comment: There are a lot of questions to your code. Why do you pass `M(T*)` as a template argument to `std::function` (it should be simple `M` due to the logic of the program)? Expression `t->*member` can't be used without argument list as I know. It has no type. And so on...

Comment: I'm sorry about `M(T*)`, this part is right. But construction `t->*member` [without arguments list as I said above] can be used only for class data members, not for class function members.

Comment: It's odd because with non-const member functions the code, and the library, run fine.

Answer (score 1):

As [**Adam S**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930535/adam-s) noted in comments this error occurs when he tries to compile [this simple code](https://gist.github.com/Systemcluster/1378a6b26b483924eba4) which uses the library [*Selene*](https://github.com/jeremyong/Selene):

```
#include <selene.h>

class C {
public:
    bool get() const;
};

bool C::get() const {return true;}

int main() {
    sel::State state;
    state["C"].SetClass<C>("get", &C::get);
}
```

The compiler fails to compile the code in [`Class.h`](https://github.com/jeremyong/Selene/blob/master/include/selene/Class.h) header. There are two overloads of function member `_register_member` of the class `Class` in it:

```
template <typename T,
          typename A,
          typename... Members>
class Class : public BaseClass {
private:

    // ...

    template <typename M>
    void _register_member(lua_State *state,
                          const char *member_name,
                          M T::*member) {
        // ...
    }

    template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
    void _register_member(lua_State *state,
                          const char *fun_name,
                          Ret(T::*fun)(Args...)) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

};
```

The compiler can't choose the second overload when a pointer to a `const` function member is passed as a third argument. There should be another overload which could accept a `const` function member. It should be declared as follows:

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
void _register_member(lua_State *state,
                      const char *fun_name,
                      Ret(T::*fun)(Args...) const)
                                            ^^^^^
```

Without such overload the compiler chooses the first overload which is created to work with pointers to data members (not function members) and fails to compile its code.

So you can't deal with `const` function members when using current version of *Selena* library (in such way as you do it at least).

Comment: Thanks you a lot! Adding the third overload (with the same method body as the second) made it work. (I'm not sure if I'm allowed to accept this as an answer though, as it admittedly fixes my original problem but I apparently asked the wrong question...)

Comment: @AdamS You can ask the question about it at [meta]. :-)

Comment: You can also use a tag dispatch for the first function template. That way, you don't have to define templates for all combinations of `const`, `volatile` and the ref-qualifiers. Just test if `M` is a function type.

Answer (score 1):

I should mention that for those viewing this now, this was in fact a bug in my code (an oversight really) and it was fixed shortly after the problem was identified.